# Best wsgi service for handling webhooks with few resources

Tags: flask, web, webhooks, uwsgi, wsgi

Currently working on a Virtual server with 2 CPU's 4GB of ram. I am running a Flask + uwsgi + nginx to host the webserver. I need the server to be capable of accepting about 10 out of 2500-ish the requests a day. The requests that don't pass average about 2ms yet the queue is consistently backed up. The issue I have been encountering lately is both speed and duplication when it does work. As the accepted webhooks are sent to another server and I will get duplicates or completely miss a bunch.

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 4
enable-threads = true
threads = 2

socket = API.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

harakiri = 10
die-on-term = true
```

This is my current .ini file I have messed around with harakiri and have read countless hours through the uwsgi documentation trying different things it is unbelievably frustrating.

[Picture of Systemctl status API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x6eW.jpg)

The check for it looks similar to this redacted some info.

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def handle_callee():
    authorization = request.headers.get('authorization')
    if authorization == SECRET and check_callee(request.json):
        data = request.json
        name = data["payload"]["object"]["caller"]["name"]
        create_json(name, data)

        return 'success', 200
    else:
        return 'failure', 204
```

The json is then parsed through a number of functions. This is my first time deploying a wsgi service and I don't know if my configuration is incorrect. I've poured hours of research into trying to fix this. Should I try switching to gunicorn. I have asked this question differently a couple of days ago but to no avail. Trying to put more context in hopes someone could point me in the right direction. I don't even know in the systemctl status whether the | req: 12/31 is how many it's done thus far and what's queued for that PID. Any insight into this situation would make my week. I've been unable to fix this for about 2 weeks of trying different configs increasing working, processes, messing with the harakiri, disabling logging. But none of this has proved to get the requests to process at a speed that I desire.

Thank you to anyone who took the time to read this, I am still learning and have tried to add as much context as possible. If you need more I will gladly respond. I just can't wrap my head around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to take a systematic approach in figuring out:

- How many requests per second can you handle
- What are your apps bottlenecks and scaling factors

Cloudbees have written a [great article on performance tuning for uwsgi + flask + nginx](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/getting-every-microsecond-out-of-uwsgi).

To give an overview of the steps to tune your service here is what it might look like:

First, you need to make sure you have the required tooling, particularly a benchmarking tool like [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html), [k6](https://k6.io/docs/examples/), etc.

1. Establish a base. This means that you configure your application with the minimum setup to run i.e. single thread and single process, no multi-threading. Run the benchmark and record the results.
2. Start tweaking the setup. Add threads, processes, etc.
3. Benchmark after the tweaks.
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3 until you see the upper limits, and understand the service characteristics - are you CPU/IO bound?
5. Try changing the hardware/vm, as some offerings come with penalties in performance due to shared CPU with other tenants, bandwidth, etc.

Tip: Try to run the benchmark tool from a different system than the one you are benchmarking, since it also consumes resources and loads the system further.

In your code sample you have two methods `create_json(name, data)` and `check_callee(request.json)`, do you know their performance?

Note: Can't comment so had to write this as an answer.